# Exclude class under <a> tag from a:hover

Tags: html, css

I have selectable boxes (`class="selectbox"`) with their own hover behaviour, so any link text within these boxes should be excluded from the general `a:hover` effect. I tried to use the `:not()` CSS pseudo-class as suggested in other answers on SO but can't get it to work.

```
<!-- Link within box, should not have hover effect -->
<a href="XXX">
  <div class="selectbox">
    <article class="media">
      <div>
        <p>
        Link within box
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</a>

<!-- General link, should have hover effect -->
<a href="XXX">General link</a>
```

CSS I have tried:

```
a:not(.selectbox):hover {
    text-shadow: 1px 0 0 currentColor;
}
```

```
a:not(a > .selectbox):hover {
    text-shadow: 1px 0 0 currentColor;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:not` wouldn't work here since you wanna know wether it contains some element or not. You could use [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) like below but the support accros browsers isn't the best.

```css
a:hover {
    text-shadow: 1px 0 0 currentColor;
}
a:has(.selectbox):hover{
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="XXX">
  <div class="selectbox">
    <article class="media">
      <div>
        <p>
        Link within box
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</a>

<!-- General link, should have hover effect -->
<a href="XXX">General link</a>
```

Or use a selector with higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for what's within the anchor, like so:

```css
a:hover {
    text-shadow: 1px 0 0 currentColor;
}
a > .selectbox {
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="XXX">
  <div class="selectbox">
    <article class="media">
      <div>
        <p>
        Link within box
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</a>

<!-- General link, should have hover effect -->
<a href="XXX">General link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm that the first solution did not work for me on Firefox (did not test other browsers) but the second one did.

Comment: Glad I could help. Yeah Firefox doesn't support `:has` yet. It's a new CSS property, that will normally cover all browsers soon.

Answer (score -3):

i tried to use :not()

```css
     a {
            display: block;
            color: green;
        }
        a:not(.child):hover {
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
```

```html
 <a href="XXX" class="parent">General link
        <a class=" child" href="XXX">
            <div class="selectbox">
                <article class="media">
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            Link within box
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </a>
    </a>
```

Comment: It's not valid to have an `a` within an `a`.